# How to specify two navigation properties from entity X to the same target entity, Y?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Consider that I have an `Instructor` class:

```
public class Instructor
{
    public InstructorTypesEnum Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> CoInstructingCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Here, `InstructorTypesEnum` has two values: instructor and co-instructor. So the two navigation properties `Courses` and `CoInstructingCourses` are supposed to return those different courses.

Of course I am also having difficulties specifying the coresponding properties in the `Course` class

```
    public Guid InstructorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Coinstructors { get; set; }
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: How *exactly* do you want instructors and courses to be related? You only show what you don't think is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [InversePropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

On your model, I think it would be (not verified):

```
public class Instructor
{
  public InstructorTypesEnum Type { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("Instructors")]
  public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("Coinstructors")]
  public virtual ICollection<Course> CoInstructingCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But what about the `Course` class? No change needed?

Comment: By specifying it once, EF has enough information to go the reverse diretion.

Answer (score 0):

What's more - you shouldn't use GUID as entity ID. It hurts performance.

```
public Guid InstructorId { get; set; }
```

Try to replace it with for example int.