# EF Core 2.1 - How to map Many-To-Many with same Types

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a very specific problem, which I would like to ask here for help.
I'm using .NET Core 2.1.1 with EF Core 2.1.1. I'm using the code first approach and currently am designing a domain model for my application.

So I have the following requirement: I have a `TrainingItem` class, which contains basic information about training. `TrainingItem` also contains a list of attendees, so I am using the many-to-many relationship between `TrainingItem` and `TrainingEmployee`. The problem is that I have a requirement that `TrainingItem` should contain a list of employees that are waiting for this training, so I came up with the following approach:

```
public class TrainingItem 
{
  // ... properties for Training
  public virtual ICollection<TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem> Attendees {get;set;} = new List<TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>();

  public virtual ICollection<TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem> WaitingList {get;set;} = new List<TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>();  
}

public class TrainingEmployee
{
    // ... properties for Employee
    public virtual ICollection<TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem> TrainingEmployeeTrainingItems {get;set;} = new List<TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>();
}

public class TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem
{
    public int TrainingEmployeeId {get;set;}
    public virtual TrainingEmployee TrainingEmployee {get;set;}

    public int TrainingItemId {get;set;}
    public virtual TrainingItem TrainingItem {get;set;}
}

// this is my model creating method in db context
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // many-to-many
    builder.Entity<TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.TrainingEmployeeId, x.TrainingItemId });
}
```

So as you can see the first list of attendees can be mapped with a workaround that is currently in EF Core used for mapping many-to-many relationships.

But the question is, how can I map WaitingList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra entity per many-to-many, so only `TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem` won't do.

Try the following:

```
public class TrainingItem 
{
  // ... properties for Training
  public virtual ICollection<AttendeeTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem> Attendees {get;set;} = new List<AttendeeTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>();

  public virtual ICollection<WaitingListTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem> WaitingList {get;set;} = new List<WaitingListTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>();  
}

public class TrainingEmployee
{
    // ... properties for Employee
    public virtual ICollection<AttendeeTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem> AttendingTrainings {get;set;} = new List<AttendeeTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>();
    public virtual ICollection<WaitingListTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem> AwaitingTrainings {get;set;} = new List<WaitingListTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>();
}

public abstract class TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem
{
    public int TrainingEmployeeId {get;set;}
    public virtual TrainingEmployee TrainingEmployee {get;set;}

    public int TrainingItemId {get;set;}
    public virtual TrainingItem TrainingItem {get;set;}
}

public class AttendeeTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem : TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem
{
}

public class WaitingListTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem : TrainingEmployeeTrainingItem
{
}

// this is my model creating method in db context
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // many-to-many
    builder.Entity<AttendeeTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.TrainingEmployeeId, x.TrainingItemId });
    builder.Entity<WaitingListTrainingEmployeeTrainingItem>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.TrainingEmployeeId, x.TrainingItemId });
}
```

Comment: I would never think of that approach, thank you very much for Your help! Appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022263/64348) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24022047/64348) before (it's worth noting your question is not a duplicate because it's for core and not old school EF).

[You can apply](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) the `InversePropertyAttribute` to your collections.

Comment: But where do I need to put InverseProperty? To which class? I am trying to understand my current setup and the InverseProperty attribute.

Comment: On the collection properties of `TrainingItem`: `Attendees` and `WaitingList`.